# Is the same meaning between using relative pronouns and adjective in sentence?

Tags: adjectives, relative-pronouns

- I want to find a car which is white in a house which is red.
- I want to find a white car in a red house.

Are two sentences above the same meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes

a car which is white = a white car

a house which is red = a red house

other possibilities include

a car of the color white /
a house of the color red

a car that is white / 
a house that is red

a white-colored car / 
a red-colored house

Comment: Wow! I just know the way of relative-pronoun and adjective. I saw the others you provided I like and I learned it now. Thanks.